# Extending formulas based on data in another sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA related question which has to do with extending formulas based on the data inserted to another sheet but with some implications. More specifically, I would like formulas in sheet "Calculation" to extend from cells A3:AB3 based on the number of rows populated in column A in the sheet "Responses". Then delete the content of cells from this point below (this is to dynamically adjust populated formulas in sheet "Calculation" in case less rows are populated in sheet "Responses" compared to the last time). The tricky part is that sheet "Responses" could be either empty (so we don't want an endless loop); populated with data through copy paste, or the user can delete it completely and insert a new tab with the same name downloaded from a database (I avoid an error in my formulas using `INDIRECT`).

Finally because sheet "Calculation" is always hidden, and as mentioned sheet "Responses" might be deleted and re-inserted don't think the code could run by targeting changes in sheet "Responses". What could work is inserting a button into a sheet called "Output" or run the code every time this sheet ("Output") is active (so maybe save the code there).

What I have is very simple and doesn't do what I need at all. I can't get it to read from another sheet only from column AD within the same sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AD:AD")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    lastrow = Range("AD3000").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A3:AB3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:AB" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you show the code you already have ?

Comment: Hi Mitch - have updated the question. It is something I have found in stackoverflow but doesn't do what's needed. Thanks.

Comment: 1st, in sheet Calculation, does it always contain data that you are adding to, or can it be cleared each time you run ? 2nd, to read from another sheet, you must use a "qualified" location, ie: `Sheets("Calculation").Range("AD:AD")`. Just using Range assumes ActiveSheet. 3rd, you must count the number of active rows in column A using something like `CountA` or `CountIf`. 4th, using `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` requires "Target" somewhere in your script, which you don't have. Let me think on this a bit.

Comment: @Mitch 1) In sheet Calculation I have the formulas in row 3 (A3:AB3) and these are the ones I want to extend. The reason is to make the workbook lighter and faster. If I extend them up to row 2500 (won't need more than 3000) it's very slow. And would be great to dynamically reduce the rows that have formulas depending on the rows populated in A:A in sheet Responses. But even if it doesn't do that its fine. Just starting from A3:AB3 and extending up to the point we need without deleting the rest is still ok...  I can add a button to delete manually - totally fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your sheet will be deleted, you can use `Workbook_SheetChange` event, inside `ThisWorkbook` module, and check if `sh.Name = "Responses"` to apply the code's logic.

**Code** (inside `ThisWorkbook` module)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CalcSht As Worksheet

' set Worksheet object
Set CalcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations")

With Sh
    If .Name = "Responses" Then ' check if changes were made in a worksheet named "Responses"
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        ' --- First: clear formulas form all cells (below row 3) ---
        LastRow = CalcSht.Cells(CalcSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  ' get the last row in column A
        If LastRow < 4 Then LastRow = 4
        CalcSht.Range("A4:AB" & LastRow).ClearContents ' clear contents (formulas) from row 4 and below


        ' --- Second: populate formulas on all rows after row 3 (where there is data in column A) ---
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  ' get the last row in column A

        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            ' drag formulas until last row with data in column A (in "Responses" worksheet)
            CalcSht.Range("A3:AB3").AutoFill Destination:=CalcSht.Range("A3:AB" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End If
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Shai! I added `If LastRow < 4 Then LastRow = 4` also after the second **Last Row** as it seemed to work better if the rows in sheet "Responses" were 0 or 1.